# Print Dictionary in Python ttk

Tags: python, dictionary, ttk

I need to display a python dictionary in ttk.  So currently the user inputs values and those are stored in a dictionary, after each entry the dictionary will update with the new value.  I want to print these values in a nice neat vertical column.  Updating the new value at the bottom of the column each time the user inputs.

I am aware of this method, but don't know how to map it to TK:

```
>>> D = {'d1': {'a':'1'}, 'd2': {'b':'2'}, 'd3': {'c':'3'}}
>>> for k, d in D.items():
    print k, d

d2 {'b': '2'}
d3 {'c': '3'}
d1 {'a': '1'}
```

Problem with this is if I set the "print k, d" to my TTK label widget it is just going to update the widget each time it goes through essentially only displaying the last variable it runs through.

So how would I get it to display a dictionary with each value/key on a new line and not "forget" the previous value when it updates?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what TTK label variable you are referring to.Could you please clarify.

Comment: well in ttk there is a label widget and I was going to use that to display the values in the gui.  If there is a diff widget that would work better please elaborate.  This may help : [Tk tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/widgets/label.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a string. Then set it as the text of the label.

For example:

```
from Tkinter import *   # Python 3.x: from tkinter import *
from ttk import *       # Python 3.x: from tkinter.ttk import *

D = {'d1': {'a':'1'}, 'd2': {'b':'2'}, 'd3': {'c':'3'}}

root = Tk()
lb = Label(root, text='')
lb['text'] = '\n'.join('{} {}'.format(k, d) for k, d in D.items()) # <---
# OR lb.config(text=....)
# OR lb.configure(text=...)
lb.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see what you are doing here but its not working for me.  When I tried to plug it into my code into the template you gave here it tells me an "items has not object" error.  So I tried to just run your code to make sure it was working correctly and I got a "TypeError:  'NoneType' object does not support item object"...... something is up with that D.items(), am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, this ended up working.  It just took some tweaking to get it to work with my code the " '\n'.join('{} {}'.format(k, d) for k, d in D.items())" is the important part.